# Apache HttpClient and remote files in URL with https scheme

Tags: java, https, apache-commons-httpclient

I'm using version 4.2.5. of [AutoRetryHttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/AutoRetryHttpClient.html) from org.apache.httpcomponents to download a pdf file from an url whose scheme is **https**. The code is written in NetBeans 7.3 and uses JDK7.

Supposing that the imaginary pdf resource is at `https://www.thedomain.with/my_resource.pdf`, then I have the following code:

```
SchemeRegistry registry = new SchemeRegistry();
    try {
        final SSLSocketFactory sf = new SSLSocketFactory(new TrustStrategy() {
            @Override
            public boolean isTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                    throws CertificateException {
                return true;
            }
        });

        registry.register(new Scheme("https", 3920, sf));            
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException | KeyStoreException | UnrecoverableKeyException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HttpConnection.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }        
    //Here I create the client.
    HttpClient client = new AutoRetryHttpClient(new DefaultHttpClient(new PoolingClientConnectionManager(registry)),
            new DefaultServiceUnavailableRetryStrategy(5, //num of max retries
               100//retry interval)); 

        HttpResponse httpResponse = null;
        try {
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("https://www.thedomain.with/my_resource.pdf");
            //I set header and Mozilla User-Agent
            httpResponse = client.execute(httpget);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
        ... //other lines of code to get and save the file, not really important since the code is never reached
```

When I call `client.execute` the following exception is thrown

```
org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to https://www.thedomain.with refused
```

**What can I do to get that pdf resource?**

PS: I can download it via browser, so exists a way to obtain that file.

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be a couple of problems:

- You registered the Scheme to use 3920 as the default port, which is a non-standard port number for HTTPS. If the server is actually running on that port, then you would have to access using this URL in the browser: `https://www.thedomain.with:3920/my_resource.pdf`. Since the URL that you use in the browser does not include the 3920 port, then the server will be running on the default port of 443, so you should use change `new Scheme("https", 3920, sf)` to `new Scheme("https", 443, sf)`.
- It appears that the CN in your server's certificate doesn't match its hostname, which is causing the `SSLPeerUnverifiedException`. In order for this to work, you would need to use the `SSLSocketFactory(TrustStrategy, HostnameVerifier)` constructor and pass a verifier that doesn't do this check. Apache provides the [`AllowAllHostnameVerifier`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/conn/ssl/AllowAllHostnameVerifier.html) for this purpose.

**Note:** You really shouldn't use the no-op TrustStrategy and HostnameVerifier in production code, as this essentially turns off all security checks in terms of authenticating the remote server and leaves you open to impersonation attacks.

Comment: If I use standard 443 port I get `javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated`. However, If I use the suggested domain with your additional port specification I still get the `org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException` exception

Comment: SSLPeerUnverifiedException means that you're at least talking to the server on the right port, but getting an SSL error. Connection refused typically means you're using the wrong port number.

Comment: Ok, suppose that I use port 443, as expected, and that I specify it in the URL. Do you know why the code doesn't work?

Comment: If you changed the code to say `new Scheme("https", 443, sf)` and it still gives SSLPeerUnverifiedException then no, I don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: @mat_boy see edits for a possible fix for the SSLPeerUnverifiedException

Comment: `SslContextFactory` doesn't seem to be part of _org.apache.httpcomponents_. However, exists the same constructor for `SSLSocketFactory`: I tried the changes suggested at point two, but nothing changed (with both ports)